# Devo editar o título de uma pergunta a fim de torná-la mais objetiva?

Tags: debate, suporte, edição, título

<s>Uma pergunta deve ser uma pergunta?</s>

Nem sempre os usuários novatos da nossa comunidade dão um título intuitivo para a questão, normalmente utilizam o corpo da pergunta para fazer isso. Já os mais experientes até o fazem, dão um título compreensivo mas sem a "cara" de pergunta de sites Q&A.

Gostaria de saber se, para a comunidade, está tudo bem editar esses títulos e:

1. **Torná-los intuitivos**. Entendo o conteúdo da pergunta é de suma importância (me refiro ao detalhamento) mas o título é ainda mais. Ele é a primeira coisa que outros usuários e visitantes vão ver e deve dar uma introdução ao que será tratado na pergunta.
2. **Tornar uma pergunta, uma pergunta**.

   ```
   O que vocês acham. É uma boa ideia
   ```

   ou

   ```
   O que vocês acham? É uma boa ideia?
   ```

Alguns exemplos:

<kbd>Jquery Recuperar valor de um atributo gerado apos</kbd>
<kbd>Como recuperar o atributo de um elemento criado dinamicamente?</kbd>
- [Link da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47077/como-recuperar-o-atributo-de-um-elemento-criado-dinamicamente)

<kbd>Mudar icone de um arquivo .jar</kbd>
<kbd>Como alterar o ícone de um arquivo .jar?</kbd> - [Link da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47120/como-alterar-o-%C3%ADcone-de-um-arquivo-jar)

<kbd>Diferença entre printf e print</kbd>
<kbd>Qual a diferença entre printf e print?</kbd> - [Link da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47102/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-printf-e-print)

<kbd>Enviar/receber arquivo via Socket C++</kbd>
<kbd>Como enviar e receber um arquivo via Socket?</kbd> - [Link da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45848/como-enviar-e-receber-um-arquivo-via-socket)

<kbd>Dados para novo kinect</kbd>
<kbd>Onde posso encontrar informações sobre o Kinect v2?</kbd> - [Link da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47119/onde-posso-encontrar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-sobre-o-kinect-v2)

Comment: +1 Excelente pergunta, as vezes também tenho essas dúvidas. Costumo alterar quando é "dúvida sobre php". Em casos que seja só mudar para uma frase interrogativa não sei se será necessário.

Comment: Ia perguntar isso agora. Muito bom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## TL;DR

Não existe uma regra definitiva. Use o bom senso.

## Discussões anteriores sobre alterações mínimas

Já discutimos aqui no meta um pouco sobre alterações mínimas. `//TODO: procurar link`

Por exemplo, arrumar uma vírgula, um ponto ou um acento.

O problema com alterações muito pequenas é que não contribuem praticamente nada para efetivamente melhorar o conteúdo. Alguns usuários usam isso para obter facilmente alguns pontinhos e medalhas em edições.

Esse tipo de edição deve ser rejeitado nas filas de análise para evitar o abuso do sistema.

## Uso do bom senso

Entretanto, se a mudança faz algumas diferença para o entendimento da pergunta ou da resposta, então eu diria para você ir em frente.

Algumas vezes uma interrogação pode fazer a diferença. Quem dirá um título mais claro para a pergunta.

As edições a partir de outros usuários são para melhorar a clareza mesmo, pois em geral adicionar mais conteúdo depende do autor.

Eu mesmo já editei perguntas modificando e trocando a ordem de umas 3 palavras a fim de tornar o título mais claro para salvar a pergunta de um fechamento. Mas isso depende muito da situação.

Algumas vezes um usuário ou outro vê perguntas com erros de português como um sinal de baixa qualidade e não se dá ao trabalho de procurar compreender, portanto em alguns casos correções ortográficas e gramaticais efetivamente salvam uma pergunta.

## A regra que não é uma regra

Como (acho eu) o Gabe diria, reflita sobre isso:

> **Esta edição faz deste site ou da internet um lugar melhor?**

Comment: +1 Adorei o `//TODO: procurar link` :D

Comment: O Gabe diria exatamente isso

Comment: Algumas das minhas perguntas começaram a receber visitantes de fora (possivelmente muitos usuários da busca do Google) por trocar 2 ou 3 palavras de ordem. Eu acho essas edições bem plausíveis, pois muitas vezes o título reflete as palavras-chaves das perguntas, e não especificamente uma pergunta.

Comment: @biio Sim, em alguns casos isso realmente pode ajudar. Só devemos tomar cuidado para não exagerar e começar a fazer SEO no site inteiro.

Comment: Quando se coloca um "//TODO" ele sempre fica lá sem resolver, como esse que está aí há 2 anos :D