# Sugestão de tópico de ajuda: como escrever um título

Tags: debate

Percebo muitos títulos de perguntas no SOpt que são extremamente vagas, não indicando de modo nenhum sobre qual o problema específico que será detalhado no texto da pergunta. Exemplos (do momento, na lista de recentes):

- "Problema NullPointerException Java Web",
- "DÚVIDA Spring Boot Hibernate",
- "Adaptar leitor de arquivo txt".

O título deveria dar uma ideia mais específica de que tipo de problema se quer tratar (que é um problema todos já sabem, senão, não estariam perguntando no SO =)). Ajuda, a quem acha que pode resolver, a notar a pergunta; e ajuda quem está procurando uma solução para um problema de mesma natureza. Um bom exemplo:

- "Qual é a diferença entre i++ e ++i?".

Deixo aqui então, uma sugestão para criar um tópico na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) sobre "Como criar um bom título".

Comment: Mas já tem isso no [ask]

Comment: Infelizmente também quase ninguém segue ou lê esses tópicos de ajuda. Mas nada impede você edite os títulos que achar que podem ser melhorados, alias, isso é o recomendado para estes casos. Costuma-se adquirir esse tipo de experiencia com o tempo de participação do site, muitos usuários iniciantes começam assim e depois melhoram absurdamente seus posts. O que nós, "veteranos", podemos fazer é usar  as ferramentas que estão ao nosso alcance, que é a edição e o comentário auxiliando-o na melhora de sua pergunta.

Comment: @Articuno - você diz no trecho "Se você fizer uma pergunta vaga, terá uma resposta vaga. Porém, se você der detalhes e contexto, podemos fornecer uma resposta útil."? Porque eu acho que isso está vago (ha!) para se entender que também se trata do título. Por exemplo, a pessoa pode ter escrito um bom texto, explicando bem o problema, mas ter dado um título vago. Nesse caso, é sempre bom ter um tópico de ajuda mais específico que um usuário possa recomendar ao autor sobre "como criar um título".

Comment: @Articuno - "Mas nada impede você edite os títulos que achar que podem ser melhorados, alias, isso é o recomendado para estes casos." - Novata aqui, vou dar uma olhada sobre edições, vi alguns títulos que precisam ser traduzidos também. Obrigada.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss - Opa, como o SO não mostrou essa como possível duplicata eu acabei achando que não tinha. Daquela discussão foram resolvidas algumas ações, pelo que entendi. Mas elas foram feitas?

Comment: @mari isso deve ajudar: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3827/3635 / https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4394/3635 / https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4385/3635 / https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2376/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Certo, então devemos editar o título para deixá-lo mais claro. Só ficou pendente, creio, o item da ajuda sobre como criar um titulo. Mas vejo que essa questão já foi bem discutida.